# Data Factory - Retrieve value from field with dash "-" from JSON file

Tags: json, azure-data-factory

In my pipeline I reach through REST API using GET request to a 3rd party database. As an output I receive  a bunch of JSON files. The number of JSON files I have to download (same as number of iterations I will have to use) is in one of the fields in JSON file. The problem is that the field's name is 'page-count' which contains "-".

```
@activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.meta.page.page-count
```

Data Factory considers dash in field's name as a minus sign, so I get an error instead of value from that field.

```
{"code":"BadRequest","message":"ErrorCode=InvalidTemplate, ErrorMessage=Unable to parse expression 'activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.meta.page.['page-count']'","target":"pipeline/Product_pull/runid/f615-4aa0-8fcb-5c0a144","details":null,"error":null}
```

This is how the structure of JSON file looks like:

```
 "firstRow": {
        "meta": {
            "page": {
                "number": 1,
                "size": 1,
                "page-count": 7300,
                "record-count": 7300
            },
            "non-compliant-record-count": 7267
        }
    },
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "intergrationRuntimeTest1",
    "billingReference": {
        "activityType": "PipelineActivity",
        "billableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "SelfhostedIR",
                "duration": 0.016666666666666666,
                "unit": "Hours"
            }
        ]
    },
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 1
    }
}
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: '-' is a valid character for a JSON name, so that shouldn't be the cause. Are you sure the Lookup.output.firstRow is returning a complete JSON object? Is "page" a JSON object with a property named "page-count"? Can you share an example of the complete JSON object?

Comment: Yes, I've added the structure of the JSON file to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below syntax works when retrieving the value for a json element with a hyphen.  It is otherwise treated as a minus sign by the parser. It does not seem to be documented by Microsoft however I managed to get this to work through trial and error on a project of mine.

```
@activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.meta.page['page-count']
```

Comment: Try it why? What does it do?

Comment: Please explain in more detail why this is a solution to the question.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for us too. We had the same issue where we couldn't reference an output field that contained a dash(`-`). We referenced this post and used the square brackets and single quote and it worked!

Example below.

```
@activity('get_token').output.ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders['Set-Cookie']
```