# ADF web activity output parameter with special character

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm using ADF Web activity to submit a GET request to the external API.

[image]

From the web activity (2) I'm getting the following output:

[image]

Now, I want to assign a variable with value of the element that is marked on the screen.

Unfortunately, the following expressioin is invalid:

```
@activity('Web1').output.ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders.Total-Count
```

Is looks to me that ADF is not able to parse this expression due to special character ("-") in the name of property I'm trying to extract.

When I use a different expression to access a different parameter:

```
@activity('Web1').output.ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders.Status
```

it works.

Do you have any idea how I should write the expression to extract the value of "Total-Count" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this post [ADF retrieves value from field with dash from json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61937105/data-factory-retrieve-value-from-field-with-dash-from-json-file) this could work for you, too.
The expression in your case could look like this:

```
@activity('Web1').output.ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders['total-count']
```